# Prawn doesn't draw a horizontal rule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, prawn

I want to draw a simple horizontal rule. What I'm doing is:

```
move_down 30
horizontal_rule
```

and Gemfile

```
gem 'prawn', :git => "https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn.git", branch: 'master'
```

It doesn't draw anything.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to call horizontal_rule inside a stroke do block, i.e.

```
stroke do
  move_down 30
  horizontal_rule
end
```

Alternatively you can call the method, `stroke_horizontal_rule`.

```
move_down 30    
stroke_horizontal_rule
```

If you want to use other options such as color, width etc I think you have to do it in the block...

```
stroke do
  stroke_color 'ff0000'
  dash(5, space: 2, phase: 0)
  line_width 10
  stroke_horizontal_rule
  move_down 15
  horizontal_line(0, 540)
end
```

Comment: is it possible to specify its color, width?

Comment: but what about its width?

Comment: The width is in the example... Are you talking about the length?  The horizontal_rule spans the width of its bounds.  If you need to specify length you'll either have to create a bounding_box to contain the horizontal_rule, or use the horizontal_line which lets you specify start and end points (and therefore line length)

Comment: very helpful, again! Thanks :)